# Remove the space between two linearlayout

Tags: android, eclipse

For the output link . If you see  for linearlayout1 and linearlayout2  there would be 5dp of space how to remove it.Similarly to layout 2 ,layout 3 and layout 3, layout4.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoBFg.png

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context="com.example.examplepro.MainActivity" >  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_weight="25" >    
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:text="1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:layout_weight="0"> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn17"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn18"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn19"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its a default space with button.

Comment: Try using `negative` margin on the buttons. Like `android:margin = -10dip`.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the spaces on the Linearlayout they were actually the button background which is having shadow.Try to use custom backgroud for your Buttons.

Like:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your XML coding it's correct. Just add some default image as your back ground button. It will not show any spaces. And instead of adding wait to the buttons you can do as follows.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn22"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn23"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn24"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout31"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn31"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout32"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn32"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout33"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn33"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout34"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn34"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout41"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn41"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout42"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn42"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout43"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn43"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout44"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn44"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    tools:context="com.example.examplepro.MainActivity" >  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_weight="25" >    
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:text="1"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"> 
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:layout_weight="0"> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn17"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn18"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn19"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

just put for every linear layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing first. I see you're trying to make a GridView.

Why not use the GridView in the first place. It will handle all the stuff you've done here for you.

I believe this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

is what could be causing this behaviour. This is basically telling to "wrap_content". Try to use fill_parent or match_parent attributes.